# Limit depth in spring data jpa with hibernate and spring boot yaml configuration

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, yaml, spring-data-jpa

My web is built with spring boot, springMVC, spring data JPA and hibernate. I know hibernate has a config called *max_fetch_depth*. But I don't know how to config it in spring boot project with yaml format. I put it in application.yml as below:

```
spring:
  properties:
    hibernate.max-fetch-depth: 1
```

It seems doesn't work.
Any idea for it? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
       hibernate.max_fetch_depth: 1
```